# Display commenter's registration date on comments?

Tags: comments, user-registration, date

Is there any way to display a  user's (registered)  registration date on the comment.

Lets say i have a written an article, registered users A, B, C and D left a comment on my article.

I can display comment date, commenter's name and email by default .

I want to display the commenter's  registration date also.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

In your [`wp_list_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) callback function, you can call [`get_userdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) to get any additional comment author data:

```
$userdata = get_userdata( $comment->user_id );
echo 'Registered: ' . $userdata->user_registered;

// format the date
// Sunday January 13th 2013
echo 'Registered: ' . date( 'l F jS Y', strtotime( $userdata->user_registered ) );
```

Comment: It works ,,, thanks , but how do i display only the date. 2011-06-03 06:21:49   , i want to remove the time ...

Comment: I tried using ... <strong class="timestamp">  </strong> but changes to last year instead of the date !

Comment: @pradip see php's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to format the date.

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need is in the user Object pulled by [`get_user_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by).

```
$user = get_user_by('login','login-name');
var_dump($user);
```

The information may already be available though. Check your theme carefully to see what information has already been pulled.