# Getting the age of a users account

Tags: users

I am trying to find a way of getting a users membership account age?

For example - I want to display:

Member since - 2010

I have looked here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference
and all over the web but I can not find anything.

Can you help please?

Comment: Could you add the code you used to get result/output? Because, sorry to say, you didnt do a real search OR used the wrong text.... Take a look [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/80349/15605) or [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77878/15605) or [here](https://www.ideiplus.com/show-user-registration-date-in-wordpress-website/) and so on.

Comment: Hi Charles, I have already ready these three links and I am sorry to say this didn't work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer from [@Ralf912](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77878/15605) *(the second 'here' in my comment!)* is all you need/want.

This little function should help you out:
*(please make a backup of `functions.php` before adding this code snippet in that file.*

```
/**
 * Display Members registration year
 *
 * @author @Ralf912
 * @return date(year)
 * @uses   echo do_shortcode( '[memberSince]' );
 *
 * @version Wordpress 4.6.1
 */
add_shortcode( 'memberSince', 'wpse241751_display_year' );
function wpse241751_display_year(){
    $users = get_users();

    foreach( $users as $user ) {
        $udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );
        $registered = $udata->user_registered;
        printf( 'Member since %s<br>', date( 'Y', strtotime( $registered ) ) );
    }
}
```

You can use now the following shortcode `[memberSince]` for explample in a template you can add: `echo do_shortcode( '[memberSince]' );` this will display(example): **Member since 2016**

To add also a month you could change in that function `date( 'Y',` into `date( 'M Y',`.

> Please read also Codex info about: [get_userdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) and [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

---

**Last** edit/update

There is also a way to display the outcome by adding the code directly in a Template by using the following snippet.

```
 $users = get_users();
 foreach( $users as $user )
 {
    $udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );
    $registered = $udata->user_registered;
    printf( 'Member since %s<br>', date( 'Y', strtotime( $registered ) ) );
}
```

Be aware that you have to remove the shortcode from the template and that when using this approach the function is useless and therefore also should  be removed from `functions.php`.

Comment: Hey Charles, thanks for much for this but it is printing out several times - see my screenshot:

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/k8kflu5kr/

Comment: To be honest, I have no clue, and it could maybe help to add that part where it comes from, a template? Imho it shouldn't repeat itself for any reason.

Comment: Wicked no worries. Thank you very much for your help I will accept your solution. Have a great weekend :)

Comment: @Ben, thank you fro responding, I will update/edit the answer with anothor approach which (maybe)prevents the "echoing" from output on the screen. Meaning by that, code which you can use directly in a Template. Have a great weekend too.